# integer constant does 'not reduce to an integer'

Tags: objective-c

I use this code to set my constants

```
// Constants.h
extern NSInteger const KNameIndex;

// Constants.m
NSInteger const KNameIndex = 0;
```

And in a switch statement within a file that imports the Constant.h file I have this:

```
switch (self.sectionFromParentTable) {
    case KNameIndex:
        self.types = self.facilityTypes;
        break;
    ...
```

I get error at compile that read this: "error:case label does not reduce to an integer constant"

Any ideas what might be messed up?

Answer (score 22):

For C/C++ and Objective-C must the case statement have fixed values - "reduced to an integer *(read value)*" at compile time

Your constants is not a real "constant" because it is a variable and I imagine it can be changed through a pointer - ie `&KNameIndex`

Usually one defines constants as `enum`

```
enum {
    KNameIndex = 0,
    kAnotherConstant = 42
};
```

If you would use C++, or Objective-C++ (with .mm as file extension) you could use a const statement as

```
const int KNameIndex = 0;
```

Comment: The const statement is perfectly legal in Objective-C, and perfectly operational with NSInteger.

Comment: I tested here with a minimal .m file and gcc and I get the same "case label does not reduce to an integer constant" for a "const int kAA=0;" constant (even with g++)

Comment: <code>const int kTest = 0;
int main() {
  int a = 1;
  switch (a) {
  case kTest:
    break;
  }
}</code>
compiling as .m gives >> 
test1.m: In function ‘main’:
test1.m:8: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
#define KNameIndex 0

...

switch (self.sectionFromParentTable) {
        case KNameIndex:
                self.types = self.facilityTypes;
                break;
        ...
```

and it should work.

Just had the same problem and I decided to go with #define rather than enum. Works for me™ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark because I haven't used Cocoa / ObjC in a long time now, but is the member variable sectionFromParentTable not of int type?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Objective C, but I'd try chucking the 'extern'. At least if this were C++, the `Constants.m` file would not be part of the compilation unit of `Other.m`, so the value of `KNameIndex` would be unknown to the compiler. Which would explain the error; an unknowable value can't be a constant.

Does putting the definition, not just the declaration, in the `Constants.h` file help?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are stuck with using a `const int` instead of a `const NSInteger` as switch only works with built in integral types. (not sure about your syntax with const flipped around after the type).

Take a look at the related question: [Objective-C switch using objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104339/objective-c-switch-using-objects)

Comment: Note that NSInteger is defined as an int [typedef int NSInteger;] maybe you are thinking of NSNumber?

Comment: Ah, you are right. I'm still a long ways from being fluent in Objective-C.