# Objective C switch statements and named integer constants

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, switch-statement, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a controller which serves as a delegate to two scrollviews which are placed in view managed by aforementioned view controller.

To distinguish between two scroll views I'm trying to use `switch` statement (instead of simple pointer comparison with `if` statement). I have tagged both scroll views as 0 and 1 like this

```
NSUInteger const kFirstScrollView = 0;
NSUInteger const kSecondScrollView = 1;
```

When I try to use these constants in a switch statement, the compiler says that case statements are not constants.

```
switch (scrollView.tag) {
    case kFirstScrollView: {
      // do stuff
    }
    case kSecondScrollView: {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make your constants static too; compiler issue I'm sure, but that seems to fix. For some reason compiler doesn't think that just `const` is really constant, but `const static` is. I'm sure there is some weird abstract reason in the docs somewhere

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be solved through the use of an anonymous (though not necessarily so) `enum` type:

```
enum {
    kFirstScrollView = 0,
    kSecondScrollView = 1
};

switch (scrollView.tag) {
    case kFirstScrollView: {
      // do stuff
    }
    case kSecondScrollView: {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

This will compile without errors.

Comment: This is a workable solution and is what I use, but I don't understand why the constants aren't working.

Answer (score 8):

This is because case statement requires constant expression. Now in C and thus in Obj-C making a variable const does not create a true constant. Thus you are getting this error. But if you use C++ or Obj-C++ then this will work.

Some more hint is available [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/875457-const-int-still-not-enough-case-statement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554419/integer-constant-does-not-reduce-to-an-integer).

Comment: So, how can we create constants in Objective-C then? #define MY_CONSTANT 123  would be one way but Is that the only one?

Comment: define and enum. Thay both create true constant in C/Obj-C.