# Expression is not an integer constant expression in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I want to use the following expression

```
-(void)SwitchCondn{
    int expression;
    int match1=0;
    int match2=1;

    switch (expression)

    {
        case match1:

            //statements

            break;

        case match2:

            //statements

            break;

        default:

           // statements

            break;

    }
```

**But I got**

[image]

**When I research I found**

```
In order to work in Objective-C, you should define your constant either like this:
#define TXT_NAME 1
Or even better, like this:
enum {TXT_NAME = 1};
```

I have been using this methods since long time . Now my variable value will change in run time so I need to define in others way and i didn't want to use if else so is there any way of declaration variable others way

**I have had study following**

[Why can I not use my constant in the switch - case statement in Objective-C ? [error = Expression is not an integer constant expression]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585276/why-can-i-not-use-my-constant-in-the-switch-case-statement-in-objective-c-e)

[Objective C switch statements and named integer constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488026/objective-c-switch-statements-and-named-integer-constants)

[Objective C global constants with case/switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235174/objective-c-global-constants-with-case-switch)

[integer constant does 'not reduce to an integer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554419/integer-constant-does-not-reduce-to-an-integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not use my constant in the switch - case statement in Objective-C ? \[error = Expression is not an integer constant expression\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585276/why-can-i-not-use-my-constant-in-the-switch-case-statement-in-objective-c-e)

Answer (score 12):

The error `expression is not an integer constant expression` means just what it says: in a `case`, the value must be constant, as in, not a variable.

You could change the declarations above the `switch` to be constants:

```
const int match1=0;
const int match2=1;
```

Or you could use an enumeration. Or a `#define`. But you can't use non-constant variables there.

Comment: will i be able to change the value of match1 where ever i wants

Comment: Not if you want to use it in a `case`.

Comment: I have the condition that i need to declare const int match1 as universal and i need to set the value of const int match1  after i get data from server

Comment: no, as the error message points out, it's required to be a **constant**.

Comment: Then you need to use something other than a `switch`. Maybe an `if`/`else if` chain.

Comment: i have been using #define previously but i need to declare value only after i get data from server so i got the problem

Comment: Ya if/else is the option but i want to know first if switch is possible or not

Comment: Ya thanks buddy. I have upvote for your efforts. Now i will try to implement it. Hope that u do same for my questions too

Comment: Does that means using if/else is the only option left

Comment: Using `const` before `int` does _not_ make this warning go away. At least not on Xcode 7.3.1 with `GCC_WARN_PEDANTIC = YES`. The only way to make it go away is with define macro or enum.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have labeled cases, you need a ENUM type

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int, MyEnum) {
  match1 = 0,
  match2 = 1
};

- (void)switchCondn:(MyEnum)expression {

  switch (expression)
  {
    case match1:
      //statements
      break;

    case match2:
      //statements
      break;

    default:
      // statements
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: will i be able to change the value of match1 where ever i wants

Comment: I have the condition that i need to declare const int match1 as universal and i need to set the value of const int match1 after i get data from server. Can it be acheive

Comment: no, not in a switch expression. You have to use if - else or something similar

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have upvoot for your effort hope to get that in question too

Comment: Does that means using if/else is the only option left

Comment: It seems so. Or you _switch_ to Swift. The switch statement in Swift is much more powerful