# Switch statement VS If statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a lot of if statements, nested if statements, and if-else statements in my project and I'm thinking about changing them to switch statements. Some of these will have nested switch statements. I know that in terms of compiling, switch statements are generally faster. My question is, which is generally more preferred to use?

Comment: One important note - You can't use NSString values in switch statements like you can in other languages like PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224495/using-an-nsstring-in-a-switch-statement

In Obj-c, I think switch statements make sense when checking for predefined numeric constants

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an important distinction

A switch statement takes an **expression with an integer result** and matches it up to a case statement with a **constant value**.  Case statements can not be expressions... so when you need to evaluate an integer result off a set of determined values then a switch statement makes sense.

IMO, nested switch statements will probably add confusion to your code... it's not just as readable.

Here's an example of where I used a switch statement to return the appropriate data source for a UIPickerView Component

```
- (NSMutableArray *) datasourceForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {

        case HoursPickerComponent: 
            return _hours;
            break;

        case MinutesPickerComponent:            
            return _mins;
            break;

        case DaysPickerComponent:            
            return _days;
            break;

        default:
            return nil;
            break;

   }    
}
```

This is a commonn patter I use to avoid magic strings or funky conditional logic.  Since enums return an int result, I often use them for routing and decision points.  Here I created an enum for my different datasources:

```
typedef enum
{
    HoursPickerComponent = 0,

    MinutesPickerComponent = 1,

    DaysPickerComponent = 2

} MedicationPickerComponents;
```

Then my delegate code for the UIPickerView component looks like

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[self datasourceForComponent:component] count];
}
```

I feel this is a good example of how to use a switch for decision points to make code more readable.  Notice that I didn't put a lot of logic in the case statement... this way you can easily tell the intention of this switch statement by looking at it.  If I had more complex code to run, I would just stub that out in a method and call the method from my case statement.

Answer (score 4):

If the control flow is depending on the value of a variable having more than 1 or 2 values, a switch makes more sense and would be easier to read and maintain. I do not have a source to quote here, but I believe they would compile down to the same native code anyway, so its not a question of performance or efficiency. I think that you should code for readability, and as you have more conditions, a switch is preferable to multiple ifs.