# Obj-C: if statements and NSString comparison functions for efficiency and readability

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

What would be the best way to code this efficiently cause this is going to get called recursively, and creating alot of objects is no good. `+*-/, sin,cos,sqrt,pi and x,y,a,b` should be put together in three separate `if statements` unlike now where everything is seperated. Also for readability making a if statments that contains 4 `isEqualToString` is not very good.

```
    NSString *operation = topOfStack;
    if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+"]) {

    } else if ([@"*" isEqualToString:operation]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"-"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) {


    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sin"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"cos"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sqrt"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"pi"]) {


    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"x"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"y"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"a"]) {

    } else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"b"]) {

    }
```

Comment: There's no good way to do this in objective-c, honestly. The ideal way would be to use a switch statement, but unfortunately objects aren't supported in switch statements in objc.

Comment: Re: "creating alot of objects is no good" -- none of this code creates any objects.

Comment: Speaking of switch statements on NSStrings, why don't you check out this header library I made for doing switches on objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224495/using-an-nsstring-in-a-switch-statement/13114988#13114988

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a *best* way to do this, but here's another option to supplement the answers already given.

Create an NSDictionary that maps your operation name (sin, sqrt, -) to a selector, like so:

```
NSDictionary *operations = @{
    @"sin": [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(operationSin:)],
    /* other operations here */
};
```

Then your switch statement becomes a lookup.

```
NSString *operation = topOfStack;
if(operations[operation]) {
    SEL op = [operations[operation] pointerValue];
    [self performSelector:op withObject:value];  /* Or some approximation thereof */
}
else {
    /* Default action for unknown operation */
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an enum on your recognized operations, using your NSDictionary to map operation name to an NSNumber boxing your enum value.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, OperationType) {
    OperationTypeSin = 0L,
    OperationTypeSqrt,
    /* and so on */
    OperationTypeUnknown
};

/* And later...  */
NSDictionary *operations = @{
    @"sin": @(OperationTypeSin),
    /* you get the idea */
};

/* Finally ... */
NSString *operation = topOfStack;
OperationType opType = [operations[operation] unsignedIntegerValue];
switch(opType) {
    case OperationTypeSin:
        /* Much cleaner, and type-safe too */
}
```

Comment: I think you're thinking of `[self performSelector:op withObject:value]`

Comment: That's what I get for answering on my lunch break. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Preparation:**

First convert the NSString operation into a int hashcode, store that hashcode in a #define 
or constant.

**Code:**

1) convert the NSString operation into a int hashcode (tokenId).
2) Then do a switch statement on that **tokenId**.

```
int token = operationToToken(operation);
switch (token) {
case: OP_MINUS: break;
case: OP_SIN: break;
case: OP_COS: break;

}
```

Comment: Hashes can (and do) collide, and are not really intended for something like this. The other thing you don't take into consideration is case-sensitivity, which, if there is user-input should be taken care of. Not a bad solution, and there really aren't many 'good' answers in C, but I'm sure that something could be made somewhat better.

Comment: You can check if they collide or, not because you have a limited alphabet of lets say 20 operation strings. if they collide, then create a beter hashfunction, e.g by asumming each letter is a digit 0-26 in number of base 26. Checking of correct input (toLowercase() can be done in advance, the question was for efficiency in a (huge) number of recursive calls.

Comment: This is good in theory, but you've changed the problem from "compare strings to perform an action" to "write a sufficient hash function" which is more likely to create maintenance issues down the road if enough operations are added.

Comment: If you need the performance, then this is one way to go, If you don' need it, it stay with string compare and if else. However, of course there should be a unit test that checks your whole alphabet for returning a unique hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, maybe fall back to C strings, and then exploit the fact that `sin`, `cos`, `sqrt`, `pi`, `a`, `b`, `x` and `y` (almost) all start by different characters:

```
const char *s = [operation UTF8String];
switch (s[0]) {
case '+':
    // addition
    break;
case '-':
    // subtraction
    break;
case 's':
    // sine or sqrt
    switch (s[1]) {
    case 'q':
        // sqrt
        break;
    case 'i':
        // sine
        break;
    }
    break;
case 'c':
    // cosine
    break;
// et cetera...
default:
    // not found
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, what do you do when someone tries to do an arc-cos or arc-sine?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I know, I know... I just noticed that we have `sqrt` and `sin`.

Comment: it would work - but as the poster above me says - if I want to expand the calculator with more operations I´d potentially have to rewrite the whole method

Comment: @TomLilletveit You can still `strcmp()`, any decent compiler can inline it for short strings.

Comment: @H2CO3 I understand what you are trying to do with the update, but honestly it's less readable than the OP's version. I shouldn't have to dig through nested switch statements to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII And honestly, is your object-switch with 2-3 levels of method calls and the lookup overhead of `NSDictionary` faster than comparing two integers?

Comment: My version wasn't meant for speed, but for readability, and thus why I suggested it. Optimizing a string comparison using nested switch statements isn't worth it unless you are performing this millions of times a minute, which, if the OP is, then he'd better look into a true math parser, or maybe write it in assembly!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Objective-C then you could possibly do this with some cleverly named selectors.

First, create an object to encapsulate an `Operation`.

Then, create an `-initWithOperation:(NSString *)op` method. Inside this method, convert any symbol operations (`*`, `+`, etc) to unique string-identifiers (letters only).

Then, you could call `NSSelectorFromString(stringOp)` although you will have to append the `:` characters yourself if you want the methods to have arguments.

Once you have the selector, you can perform the selector using `-performSelector:` , `+performSelector:`, or call the selector manually.

Provided that you name each selector with the same name as the operation, you don't need any `if` or `switch` statements, but you will have to handle the case where you send an invalid selector.

E.g.:

```
@interface Operation : NSObject

- (id)initWithOperation:(NSString *)op;
- (void)performOperationWithValue:(float)value;
+ (float)sin:(float)value;
// ... Other operations
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *theOperation;

@end

@implementation Operation
- (id)initWithOperation(NSString *)op {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Convert symbols to unique strings
        theOperation = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:op];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)performOperationWithValue:(float)value {
    NSString *withOneParam = [self.theOperation stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(withOneParam);
    [Operation performSelector:withOneParam withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]];
}

// Class methods are the actual operation implementation...
```

In the above example, I assume you have passed `@"sin"` to the `Operation` object. This is only possible in Objective-C though as you can take advantage of named selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each symbol a number and can implement a switch case.

Comment: While yes you can do this, it makes things very ugly in the long run, and at that point, I think that using a simulated switch on objects will end up with more readable code in the long run, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224495/using-an-nsstring-in-a-switch-statement/13114988#13114988