# Keep a class-level array of instantiated objects without having to explicitly remove them

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I have a class, let's say `Chicken`, and I want a class-level method to enumerate all the currently existing `Chicken`s.  To do this, I keep a class-level `NSMutableArray` and add `self` to this in the `init` method.

This is great and my enumeration method simply returns a (non-mutable) pointer to this array.

The problem is that I can no longer deallocate a chicken by removing all pointers to it, as there is always a strong pointer left in the array.

E.g. If I do this...

```
Chicken *chick = [[Chicken alloc] init];
// Do something with the chick
chick = nil;
```

The chicken lives on because there is a strong pointer to it in the array.  I could have a `-[Chicken kill]` method, which removes it from the array, but that's not neat.

What's the neatest way around this?

Comment: Use a weak reference in the array. NSValue has support for nonretained objects, but if you want an auto-zeroing reference, you could use the second half of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224495/using-an-nsstring-in-a-switch-statement/13114988#13114988

Comment: This is a hard design to maintain once you take into account multithreading. Be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`[NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSHashTable/weakObjectsHashTable) to store objects. It is basically an array holds weak references. It is safe, and clean.

If `NSHashTable` is not available, or suitable (you want to hold key-value pair like `NSDictionary`) but you have ARC with `__weak` supported, you can use a wrapper object to hold weak reference.

I use block to hold weak ref in this example

```
NSMutableDictionary *globalDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// put object
id obj = [Foo new];
__weak id weakRef = obj;
globalDict[key] = [^() { return weakRef; } copy];

// read object
id (^block)(void) = globalDict[key];
id obj = block ? block() : nil;
if (!obj) {
    [globalDict removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Another good option. As usual, one should be careful with thread-safety and non-retained pointers.

Comment: As I'm only interested in having a bag of chickens and don't worry about the order, the NSHashTable looks simplest if I'm understanding correctly that +weakObjectsHashTable will create a table such that killing a chicken will remove it from the table?

Comment: @Thickycat yes, it is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`+ (NSValue *)valueWithNonretainedObject:(id)anObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithNonretainedObject%3a) values inside your array. To simplify your API, you can create a wrapping method of `+arrayOfAllChickens` which would iterate all non-retained values and add them to an array and return that.

Remember to remove the values from the array in `dealloc` or you could hit a bad access crash.

Comment: This is the correct approach, just note that this will not auto-zero the reference, meaning you could have issues with EXC_BAD_ACCESS should you try to send a message to a dead chicken.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Just added a comment for that exactly. :-) "Dead chicken" is a nice touch!

Comment: Thanks Leo, I wanted to mark both answers as correct but seems that's not possible so I went for the NSHashTable as I'm using that although your 'indirect with another class' method was the kind of thing that was floating around in my head when I was considering how to keep my chickens.  Hmmn, I may call the NSHashTable* 'coup'...

Comment: @Thickycat Sure, now worries. It's the better method.